# Date Output (XSLT)

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, xslt

I'm doing a conversion from a XML format to another one (with an updated schema). I did the XSLT with *altova mapforce* and I'm writing a program in C# to convert this documents.

The problem here is the date format, the XSLT is doing this job but C# is giving me a wrong output (20-14-xx-xx).
This is my C# code so far:

```cs
private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {

            XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(open.FileName);
            XDocument transformedDoc = new XDocument();

            using (XmlWriter writer = transformedDoc.CreateWriter())
            {
                XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(@"C:\XSLT\Converter.xslt")));
                transform.Transform(xmlDocument.CreateReader(), writer);
            }

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                transformedDoc.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            }

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Transform complete");
            }

        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the line in the XSLT to convert the date:

```
<IssueDate>
 <xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number(number(string($var8_resultof_first/IssueDate)), '####,##,##'), '.,', concat($var13_shared, $var1_resultof_first))"/>
</IssueDate>
```

Is possible to correct this node in the C# code?

Comment: What is the value in xml corresponding to $var8_resultof_first/IssueDate

Comment: <IssueDate>20141031</IssueDate>

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example of the input and the expected output. `<IssueDate>20141031</IssueDate>` is **not** `20-14-xx-xx`. And there are many "correct" ways to output a date - which one do you want?

Comment: input: <IssueDate>20141031</IssueDate>, output: <IssueDate>20-14-10-31</IssueDate>, expected output: <IssueDate>2014-10-31</IssueDate>, any solution is fine to me, but i need a total solution to any input date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a date given as:

```
<IssueDate>20141031</IssueDate>
```

to:

```
<IssueDate>2014-10-31</IssueDate>
```

use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(IssueDate, 1, 4), '-', substring(IssueDate, 5, 2), '-', substring(IssueDate, 7, 2))" />
```

If you need to do this with more than one date, use a named template:

```
<xsl:template name="reformat-date">
    <xsl:param name="yyyymmdd"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($yyyymmdd, 1, 4), '-', substring($yyyymmdd, 5, 2), '-', substring($yyyymmdd, 7, 2))" />
</xsl:template>
```

Example of call:

```
<xsl:call-template name="reformat-date">
    <xsl:with-param name="yyyymmdd" select="IssueDate"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

**Note**: you cannot use `format-number()` to create groups of digits of unequal size.

Comment: i´m getting this output: <IssueDate>--</IssueDate>, looks like im not getting the information....

Comment: @Bigby You did not post your input XML nor your stylesheet - so I cannot say where your implementation fails. Compare: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHUk

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="(string($var8_resultof_first/IssueDate)), concat(substring(IssueDate, 1, 4), '-', substring(IssueDate, 5, 2), '-', substring(IssueDate, 7, 2)))" />  Now this input in the XSLT is giving to me the output: <IssueDate>20141016</IssueDate>, looks like the '-' is not working properly.

Comment: @Bigby Posting snippets of code without context is useless.

Comment: i can send you the full XSLT if you need it ( is to long to post it here)

Comment: I believe I gave you all the tools you need to implement this in on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IssueDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat(concat(concat(substring($var6_resultof_string, number('1'), number('4')), '-'), substring($var6_resultof_string, number('5'), $var11_resultof_cast)), '-'), substring($var6_resultof_string, number('7'), $var11_resultof_cast))"/>
            </IssueDate>
```

FINALLY, with the help of michael.hor257k, i did a correct modification to get a correct output, Thank you m8. :)